# How to create a Android emulator of CDMA type radio?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to debug the phone settings application for a CDMA specific phone. It would be better if I can have it tested on the emulator first. But the default network available (The Android virtual network service) in the emulator is a GSM one. How can we have a CDMA based emulator?
Do I have to set any property in the Android build time?
Or Is it not possible to have a CDMA emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the emulator with option *-help* which lists all options (use *-help-all* to get the options plus explanations).

This does not explicitly mention CDMA, but I think 3G is closest to this.
So you can start the emulator with  `-netspeed umts -netdelay umts`to simulate it.
If you suspect that your app could have critical timing due to network speeds, you should also try with much slower settings like 'gsm': `-netspeed gprs -netdelay gprs`.